# Unpacking multiple function arguments from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

I have the following method which is designed to execute various methods performing web requests and continue to retry on error until an appropriate response is returned.

```
async tryUntil(funct,params){
  const f = funct
  const p = params
  let result
  let err
  do {
    try{
      err=0
      console.log(...p)
      result = await f(...p)
    }catch(error){
      err=error
      console.log(error)
    }
  } while (err!=0)
  return result
}
```

The params parameter takes in an array of arguments to feed into the method whose definition is supplied to the funct parameter.

If the first element `p[0]` in Array `p` is a string, then the rest notation `...` breaks apart the string and supplies each individual character as a separate argument to the method being called. The subsequent array positions are left out altogether. This is not the behavior I was expecting. What I need, is for each element of the array to be broken down into individual arguments to be given to the method being called.

Since the `tryUntil` method calls other methods that take in 0-5 arguments, it is important for `tryUntil` to accept a single parameter containing multiple arguments.

Comment: Why not call `f.apply(null, p)`?

Comment: Can you explain that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply MDN does a better job than I.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Heretic Monkey for the fix!

> Why not call f.apply(null, p)? – Heretic Monkey

I also had to add a check to handle situations where a single argument is provided in non-array type as a single string. Corrected code below:

```
async tryUntil(funct,params){
  const f = funct
  const p = []
  if (typeof params !== 'string'){
    for (let i in params){
      p.push(params[i])
    }
  }else{
    p.push(params)
  }
  let result
  let err
  do {
    try{
      err=0
      result = await f.apply(this.client,p)
      return result
    }catch(error){
      err=error
      console.log(error)
    }
  } while (err!==0)
}
```